# Is there any other good html package in flutter for webscrapping?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, utf-8, html-parsing

I need to scrap this website https://student.kletech.ac.in/code/index.php If i use darts html and http package i get error.

```
.
.
.
Future<void> signin() async{
  var res = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://student.kletech.ac.in/code/index.php"));
print(res.body);. // Here i get utf encoding error
}
```

If i change my url to other website the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

for scraping you can use parser package
:https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_parse